# How to get unique value with LINQ>SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ to SQL, how do I get the row with 1, 21?  I'm looking for

```
SomeId==1 
and 
SecondId is a unique entry

SomeId   SecondId
   0        20
   1        21
   1        22
   1        22
```

EDIT:

Ok, sorry.  That wasn't clear.  What I'm trying to do is generically find that row.  There might be another entry that looks like this:

```
1      25
```

And that is the only 25.  So I would get back two rows.  Without referencing specific Ids, how do I find these two rows?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your edit made your question less clear to me! So you have to find 1,25 and there may be one or many rows that have 1,25? But you don't want to specifically **ask** for 1,25 (by referencing their id's)? If this is the case, how do you even know you have what you want if you were handed these rows (as you don't have their id's)?

Comment: I'm with Kevek - it's really unclear what the parameters are to the query. Okay, so you've got those rows in the database - but what information do you have about what you're trying to find?

Comment: @Kevek: There is only one row that has 1, 25 (i.e., "And that is the only 25").  Generally, I want SomeId==1.  That is easy and explicit.  Second part is also get SecondId that has only one entry of that value.  You can see above, only two rows meet that criteria.

Comment: @4thSpace Are you saying you would like to find any combination of SomeId & SecondId where there are more than one row for that combination?

Comment: @Kevek: SomeId will always equal 1 in the criteria I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, it was *really* unclear what you meant before, but now I think I see what you mean, and you want something like:

```
var query = from row in table
            where row.SomeId == targetId
            group row by row.SecondId into g
            where g.Count() == 1
            select g.Single();
```

In other words:

- Filter by `SomeId` first
- Group by `SecondId`
- Filter so that only groups with a single entry for that `SecondId` are returned
- Select the sole entry from that group

There can be multiple such groups, of course - so you *would* get (1, 21) and (1, 25) in your example.

Comment: @4thSpace: Okay, that was *very* unclear from the question description, but I think my edited answer now does what you want.

Comment: Is it possible you could provide an example of how it would be done if this were LINQ to Objects?  Each of the above rows would be an object with two properties.  They would be in a List<> of the object type.

Comment: @4thSpace: It would be exactly the same query. You shouldn't need to change it *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: If you saying you would like to find any combination of SomeId & SecondId where there are more than one row for that combination? then you could do the following:

```
var results = source.Where(x => x.SomeId == 1).GroupBy(x => x.SecondId).Where(g => g.Count > 1);
```

This will give you groups of results, and only return those that have more than one row. So in your example, you would get a group that returns 1,22...

If you are looking for the case where you only have rows in which there is a single entry in the table with that combination (the opposite of what I'm returning) you can change the comparison operator from '>' to '==' and another answer-er has also shown this possibility.

Comment: Might I suggest `source.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SomeId == 1 && x.SecondId == 21)` (both shorter and stricter)

Comment: @sehe Certainly! I modified my answer to include your suggestion, and certainly credit goes to you. I learned something new today :)

Comment: I'd also suggest avoiding `if (constant == variable)` - there's no need for it in C# (except in a *very* few special cases with `bool`) and it's generally deemed harder to read than `if (variable == constant)`

Comment: @Jon Skeet I have heard that before, and I understand that there is no need... but I personally like reading it far better, and it certainly does keep one from some silly errors in other languages. I can try to remember to do it the other way around for readability on StackOverflow, though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: is there a source you can quote on that? I love the `(null == ...)` style especially for readability; I hope you someone can finally point me at that research that showed that it was harder to read (and perhaps, why). I never fully understood (beyond: _convention_, like any coding standard)

Comment: @Kevek: I find it's best to treat each language separately - they have their own idioms, and their own ways of doing something. It's best not to write C# with a Java accent or vice versa, etc.

Comment: @sehe: I've asked various people at various times in various situations - it's only anecdotal, but most people prefer to find out what they're being asked about before the value they're checking against. I'd love to see research too...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I think I like the style partially because then I immediately know that I'm going against some variable. It distinguishes between `if (constant == variable)` and `if (variable1 == variable2)` very quickly even if you're not reading in an IDE. But that's sort of a particular case based on your own personal setup, I suppose!